# gcc reverse_iterator comparison operators missing?

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, iterator

I am having a problem using const reverse iterators on non-const containers with gcc.  Well, only certain versions of gcc.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const char v0[4] = "abc";
    vector<char> v(v0, v0 + 3);

    // This block works fine
    vector<char>::const_iterator i;
    for (i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
        cout << *i;
    cout << endl;

    // This block generates compile error with gcc 3.4.4 and gcc 4.0.1
    vector<char>::const_reverse_iterator r;
    for (r = v.rbegin(); r != v.rend(); ++r)
        cout << *r;
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This program compiles OK and runs with gcc 4.2.1 (Mac Leopard) and with Visual Studio 8 and 9 (Windows), and with gcc 4.1.2 (Linux).

However, there is a compile error with gcc 3.4.4 (cygwin) and with gcc 4.0.1 (Mac Snow Leopard).

```
test.cpp:18: error: no match for 'operator!=' in 'r != std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::rend() [with _Tp = char, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]()'
```

Is this a bug in earlier versions of gcc?

Due to other problems with gcc 4.2.1 on Mac, we need to use gcc 4.0.1 on Mac, so simply using the newer compiler is not a perfect solution for me.  So I guess I need to change how I use reverse iterators.  Any suggestions?

Comment: For a workaround, would `!(r == v.rend())` work? Alternatively you could try it with the non-reverse version via `r.base()`.

Comment: More likely an omission; I think full support for the entire STL is *still* on-going, though very close.  Back in the days of 3.4.4 it was somewhat incomplete.

Comment: @gf Nice try, "!(r == v.rend())" does not work.  Both "!=" and "==" operators are missing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a defect in the current standard: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#280

**Edit**: Elaborating a bit:
The issue is that, in the current standard:

- `vector::reverse_iterator` is specified as `std::reverse_iterator<vector::iterator>`, and `vector::const_reverse_iterator` as `std::reverse_iterator<vector::const_iterator>`.
- The relational operators on `std::reverse_iterator` are defined with a single template parameter, making `reverse_iterator<iterator>` and `reverse_iterator<const_iterator>` non-comparable.

In your code, you compare a `const_reverse_iterator` with the result of calling "rend()" on a non-const vector, which is a (non-const) `reverse_iterator`.

In C++0x, two related changes are made to fix issues like this:

- Relational operators on reverse_iterator now take two template parameters
- Containers like vector have extra methods to explicitely request a const_iterator: cbegin(), cend(), crbegin() and crend().

In your case, a workaround would be to explicitely request the const_reverse_iterator for rend():

```
vector<char>::const_reverse_iterator r;
const vector<char>::const_reverse_iterator crend = v.rend();
for (r = v.rbegin(); r != crend; ++r)
    cout << *r;
```

Comment: Nice answer.  It is more a bug in the standard than a bug in gcc.

Comment: @Christopher Bruns: I guess that making crend non-const, like r, would make things work.

Comment: @Eric Malenfant: re your fist bullet point: I think const_reverse_iterator is defined as "reverse_iterator<const_iterator>", not just "const_iterator"

Comment: @Christopher Bruns: True. A case of "missing edit after copy and paste" error. Fixed and thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

Random things I would try:

Cast the return from rend() to a const_reverse_iterator to see if the issue is in comparing a regular to a const iterator:

```
r != static_cast<vector<char>::const_reverse_iterator>(v.rend())
```

If that doesn't work, how about changing r from a const_reverse_iterator to a regular reverse iterator.

No clue if these work, but that's what I'd try in this situation.

Comment: That cast does correct the problem.  It's not very pretty but it does work.

Answer (score 2):

Since the iterators need to be the same type to be comparable, and a non-const container yields non-const iterators, why not declare and initialize the end iterator at the same time.

```
for (vector<char>::const_reverse_iterator r = v.rbegin(), end_it = v.rend(); r != end_it; ++r)
    cout << *r;
```

With an older compiler this might even give a small performance benefit.

Answer (score 1):

It *could* be a bug in the old vesion of gcc, but my guess is that the bug is in your code -- you've failed to `#include <iterator>`. It's probably only worth looking further if fixing that doesn't fix the problem.

On the other hand, if you're using the `reverse_iterator` as shown (i.e. the body of the loop is `cout << *r;`) you should probably just use `std::copy`:

```
std::ostream_iterator<char> output(std::cout);

// frontwards
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), output);

// backwards
std::copy(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), output);
```

There is also a `copy_backwards`, but I don't believe it'll do what you want.

Edit: One other possibility to consider: if adding the required header doesn't work, and you really need the reverse iterator, you might consider using [STLPort](http://www.stlport.org/download.html) in place of the native library (at least for the older compilers).

Comment: Adding "#include <iterator>" does not change the behavior.